# Flex images and positioning issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I'm trying to achieve, once I reduce the size of the screen and some elements starts to move to a second line, keep them organized to the left, instead of centered (based on the number of elements on that row). This image might help
[image]

And this is my actual code, what I'm doing wrong?

```css
#teamBoxesWrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: ;
  width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#teamUser {
  width: 250px;
  /* 20% of the viewport width */
  height: 250px;
  background-color: ;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.teamUser4 {
  background-image: url('../images/empleado4.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="teamBoxesWrapper">
  <div id="teamUser" class="teamUser4">
    <div id="teamUserPopup4" class="teamUserDetails">
      <div id="teamUserTextAligner">
        <h3 class="teamUserText1">Manuel Brenes</h3>
        <hr class="userHr" />
        <h3 class="teamUserText2">Graduado Social y
          <br>Derechos Laborales</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im confused, you're asking to ensure elements are left aligned (not centered) but your image seems to say the opposite?

Comment: Can you make a working demo with more than one box?

Answer (score 0):

On your code try replacing your justify-content: space-between for center;

Comment: Sorry the image is wrong! I did the opposite, the actual squares from that row are evenly spaced based on the full width, what I'm trying to achieve is to organize them to the left, under the elements of the first line @Pedro Martins